# Link-table column that must be able to contain both FOREIGN KEY and a special value

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I need to represent the following information in a data base (simplified):

1. A set of "Bills". (in a table `Bills`)
2. A set of "Representatives". (in a table `MPs`)
3. The authors of each bill.

   - If only "Representatives" could be authors this would be a simple link-table with FOREIGN KEYs to both `Bills` and `MPs`.
   - There is one (only one) other "Entity" that can also be an author of a bill so:

     - I can repurpose `NULL` to mean the "Entity" but this is ugly.
     - I can simply forget about FOREIGN KEY constraints but this is even uglier.

What is the **correct** way to represent this information according to database theory?

Would it be appropriate to have one table `linktable_authors` that links `Bills` and `MPs` for "Bills" authored by "Representatives", and one other table `authored_by_The_Entity` only for "Bills" authored by "Entity" (if I am dead sure that no other entities will emerge later in time)?

Bonus question:
What if there was also a table "Other_Entities" and both "Other_Entities" and "Representatives" can be authors of "Bills"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an entity **Authors** with PK **AuthorID**. Have the PK of the sub-entities **Representatives** and **OtherEntities** be **AuthorID**, to create a type-of relationship. Add an attribute **AuthorType** to **Authors** to distinguish the sub-types from conflicting. Place all attributes common to authors in the **Authors** entity.

BTW: NULL never means "some other known value". It can sensibly mean "doesn't apply" or "not known yet", amongst a few other choices, but giving it the semantics of "some other known value" is a sure sign of poor design.

Comment: I guess this is answering my "bonus question", but isn't it an overkill for the original question (only one possible author that is not a representative)?

Comment: Once you raised the existence of a business rule allowing the bonus situation, you killed all reason to consider only the simpler situation. Always design for the more general situation unless there is an overwhelming reason not to; because you will need it sooner than you think.

Comment: I agree, but for educational purposes I am really interested in a solution for the original question.

Comment: But Authors can be either Representatives or OtherAuthors. The correct solution to the first problem is to NOT ASSUME that there is only ever a single OtherAuthor.

Comment: I understand. I will wait a bit and probably select this as the accepted answer. On the other hand, could you add to your answer whether there are any glaring problems with the two-table solution that I suggested in my modified question?

Comment: BTW: NULL **never** means "some other known value". It can sensibly mean "doesn't apply" or "not known yet", amongst a few other choices, but giving it the semantics of "some other known value" is a sure sign of poor design.